# Castle Custom Lifestyle per Resolve

Tags: castle-windsor

With Castle Windsor, let's say I have the following classes:

```
public class LowLevelComponent
{
}

public class HighLevelComponent
{
    readonly LowLevelComponent LowLevelComponent;

    public HighLevelComponent(LowLevelComponent lowLevelComponent)
    {
        LowLevelComponent = lowLevelComponent;
    }
}

public class ComponentBeingResolved
{
    readonly LowLevelComponent LowLevelComponent;
    readonly HighLevelComponent HighLevelComponent;

    public ComponentBeingResolved(LowLevelComponent lowLevelComponent,
                                  HighLevelComponent highLevelComponent)
    {
        LowLevelComponent = lowLevelComponent;
        HighLevelComponent = highLevelComponent;
    }
}
```

Registered in the easiest possible way:

```
container.Register(Component.For<LowLevelComponent>());
container.Register(Component.For<HighLevelComponent>());
container.Register(Component.For<ComponentBeingResolved>());
```

I'd like to get the same instance of `LowLevelComponent` used in all dependencies ***each time I call Resolve***.

So, after these calls:

```
var instance1 = container.Resolve<ComponentBeingResolved>();
var instance2 = container.Resolve<ComponentBeingResolved>();
```

The following assertions should be true:

```
instance1.LowLevelComponent == instance1.HighLevelComponent.LowLevelComponent
instance1.LowLevelComponent != instance2.LowLevelComponent
instance1.HighLevelComponent != instance2.HighLevelComponent
```

I'll also take *"you're doing **everything** wrong, this is what you should do instead"* as an answer :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reuse a transient dependency in same context with Castle Windsor DI container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986747/how-to-reuse-a-transient-dependency-in-same-context-with-castle-windsor-di-contai)

Comment: Same problem as that question, check out Germán's contextual lifestyle: http://blog.schuager.com/2010/11/contextual-lifestyle-reloaded.html

Comment: @MauricioScheffer: Looks exactly like what I need! But is there a way to avoid creating the scopes manually? For example, if I use the typed factory facility...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Mauricio's link, I got it working using factories:

```
public interface IComponentFactory
{
    T Get<T>();
}

var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
container.Register(Component.For<LowLevelComponent>()
         .LifeStyle.Custom<ContextualLifestyle>());
container.Register(Component.For<HighLevelComponent>()
         .LifeStyle.Custom<ContextualLifestyle>());
container.Register(Component.For<IComponentFactory>().AsFactory());
//Register the "context-root" component in a child container
var subContainer = new WindsorContainer();
subContainer.Register(Component.For<ComponentBeingResolved>()
            .LifeStyle.Transient);
container.AddChildContainer(subContainer);
container.Register(
    Component.For<ComponentBeingResolved>()
        .LifeStyle.Transient
        //Here's the magic
        .UsingFactoryMethod(
            () =>
                {
                    using (new ContainerContext(container))
                        return subContainer.Resolve<ComponentBeingResolved>();
                }));
```

Usage:

```
var factory = container.Resolve<IComponentFactory>();
var instance1 = factory.Get<ComponentBeingResolved>();
var instance2 = factory.Get<ComponentBeingResolved>();
```

Not sure if this is a good hack or an ugly one, but it works wonderfully.

Comment: is the child container necessary?

Comment: @MauricioScheffer: It's the way I found to avoid a stack overflow if I call Resolve directly on the Kernel/Container

Answer (score 0):

You must've heard people recommending to only call Resolve **once** for your app entry point (Main, Controller, etc.). Castle documentation has good [guidelines](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Three-Calls-Pattern.ashx) on this.

Comment: Yes, I've read that article, and I guess I could use typed factories to obtain `ComponentBeingResolved`, but that doesn't solve the problem, does it?